# can't remove object user from Arraylist

Tags: java

Can someone help me with my code please. Im a begginer and this thing called java really confusses me :) my problem is that i have to remove user/s, but my ouput is allways just user name not found... thanks in advance

```
public void removeUser() {
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    int checks = 1;
    if (checks == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < userList().size(); i++) {

            System.out.println("Input user name for the account you want to be deleted");
            userName = input.next();

            if (userList.equals(userName)) {
                userList.get(i);
                userList.remove(userName);
                System.out.println("You succesfully removed user acount");
                System.out.println("If you want to exit press 0, if you want to continue press 1");
                checks = input.nextInt();

            } else {
                System.out.println("User name not found");
            }
        }
    }
    if (checks == 0) {

        administrator();
    }

}
```

Comment: We really need to see the code for `userList`  The problem likely is there, not in the code you have shown.

Comment: What type of data is `userList` actually holding?

Comment: Also, `userList.equals(userName)` is unlikely to ever be true, perhaps you mean `userList.contains(userName)`

Answer (score 0):

why do you think that this would work?

```
if (userList.equals(userName))
```

??

Maybe just try removing it

```
boolean removed =  userList.remove(userName);

if (removed) {
       System.out.println("You succesfully removed user acount");
}
```

No looping required

see
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

So your code could look like

```
java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
int checks = 1;
while (checks == 1) {
        System.out.println("Input user name for the account you want to be deleted");
        userName = input.next();

        if (userList.remove(userName)) {
            System.out.println("You succesfully removed user acount");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("User name not found");
        }
        System.out.println("If you want to exit press 0, if you want to continue press 1");
        checks = input.nextInt();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing that here you do with your code is change the`if (checks == 1)` to `while` loop `while(checks == 1)`, because `if` can be executed only one time.

Second thing `if (userList.equals(userName))` is never `true`, thus the `if` clause won't be executed. You first get the user name from the list like this `String name userList.get(i);` then now you can check if it is equal like this

```
if(name.equals(userName)) //or userList.contains(userName){
    // userList.remove(userName);
    // OR
    // userList.remove(i);
}
```

**Eidt:**

You can change your code as below, maybe work for you

```
        List<String> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        userList.add("AA");
        userList.add("BB");
        userList.add("CC");
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        int checks = 1;
        while (checks == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {

                System.out.println("Input user name for the account you want to be deleted");
                String userName = input.next();

                if(userList.remove(userName)) {
                    System.out.println("You scornfully removed user account");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("User name not found");
                }
                System.out.println("If you want to exit press 0, if you want to continue press 1");
                checks = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        if (checks == 0) {
            administrator();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> customerNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    customerNames.add("john");
    customerNames.add("lily");
    customerNames.add("druid");

    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter 1 ");
    if(input.nextInt() != 1){
        System.out.println("break checks ... ...");
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < customerNames.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Input user name for the account you want to be deleted");
        if (customerNames.get(i).equals(input.next())) {
            customerNames.remove(i);
            System.out.println("You succesfully removed user acount");
            System.out.println("If you want to exit press 0 ... ...\n");
            if(input.nextInt() == 0){   //break
                break;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("User name not found... ...\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> customerNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    customerNames.add("john");
    customerNames.add("lily");
    customerNames.add("druid");

    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter 1: ");
    if(input.nextInt() != 1){
        System.out.println("break checks ... ...");
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("========= start =========");
    System.out.println("Please enter 1: ");
    while(input.nextInt() != 0){
        System.out.println("Input user name for the account you want to be deleted... ...");
        System.out.println("enter name:");
        String _name = input.next(); 
        for(int i = 0; i < customerNames.size(); i++) {
            if(_name.equals(customerNames.get(i))){
                customerNames.remove(_name);
                System.out.println("You succesfully removed user acount");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("If you want to exit press 0 ... ...\n");
        System.out.println("input numeric:");
    }
    System.out.println("========= end =========");

    //break
    if(customerNames.size() == 0){return;}
    for(String name : customerNames){//print names
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```